# Magento2 contact form in footer redirects to different page after submitting the form

Tags: magento-2.1, contact-form

Could anyone help? i want to use contact form in footer without redirects to different page after submitting the form.

Everything working fine but form redirects to different page after submitting the form. I want successful and error messages under the form.

i m using below code

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Please share your contact form details to better understand issue.

Comment: Is It redirect to yourDomain/contact ?

Comment: please show getFormAction() function from block file.

Comment: Hi rakesh thanks for your reply Please find below code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
$ves = $this->helper('Ves\Themesettings\Helper\Theme');
$vesData = $this->helper('Ves\Themesettings\Helper\Data');

$show_contactform = $ves->getContactPageCfg('contactform/show_contactform');

$show_googlemap = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/show_googlemap');
$map_api = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/map_api');
$map_api = $map_api?'key='.$map_api.'&amp;':"key=AIzaSyALraGXlzRqFlAOb-tYLhUi6o6Cq9qN4KA&amp;";
$location_lng = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/location_lng');
$location_lat = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/location_lat');
$address = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/address');
$telephone = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/telephone');
$fax = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/fax');
$enable_contactus = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/enable_contactus');
$enable_contactform = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/enable_contactform');
$custom_html = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/custom_html');
$map_width = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/map_width');
$map_height = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/map_height');
$map_zoom = (int)$ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/map_zoom');

$marker_content = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/marker_content');
if($marker_content!=''){
    $marker_content = $vesData->filter($marker_content);
}

$marker_content_staticblock = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/marker_content_staticblock');
$marker_content_width = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/marker_content_width');
$marker_content_height = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/marker_content_height');
$marker_content_position = $ves->getContactPageCfg('googlemap/marker_content_position');
?>
<div class="ves-contact">
    <div class="block">     
                    <?php if($show_contactform){ ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="block form contact">
                            <div class="block-title"><strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Write Us') ?></strong> </div>
                                <div class="block-content">
                                <form action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>"
                                id="contact-form"
                                method="post"
                                data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
                                data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
                                    <fieldset class="fieldset">
                                        <div class="field note no-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Jot us a note and we’ll get back to you as quickly as possible.') ?></div>
                                        <div class="field name required">                                            
                                            <div class="control">
                                                <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserName()) ?>" placeholder="Name" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="field email required">
                                            <div class="control">
                                                <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail()) ?>" placeholder="Email" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                                       
                                        <div class="field comment required">                                            
                                            <div class="control">
                                                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('What’s on your mind?') ?>" placeholder="What’s on your mind?" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <div class="actions">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
                                        <button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?>" class="action submit primary">
                                            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```